# TFS2010 Disaster Recovery from Backups Only

Tags: backup, disaster-recovery

I have seen a lot of discussions on how to move TFS2010, the application tier and DB tier.  We have the DB sitting on the same server as the App Tier.  I am going to test the process of recovering the TFS2010 DB in a catastrophic failure.  Therefore I will have:

1. SQL backups of all TFS and WSS DB's
2. I will have the install software for all the applications (TFS etc)

Is there a document that I can use to outline the process of installing the TFS2010 App tier and make it ready to accept the backup of my SQL TFS2010?

Answer (score 0):

[Restore an Application Tier Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793167.aspx)

[Restore Data To The Same Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252458.aspx)

[Restore Data To A Different Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx)

Comment: I will need to add that we will be putting it on a server with a different name (domain requirements).